# Allow recurring contributions on membership form

Tags: recurring-contributions

I have a membership signup form and a I have the Additional Contributions amount section enabled.  When I try to enabled Recurring Contributions, I get this error after saving it, 
Recurring Contributions
You cannot enable both Recurring Contributions and Auto-renew memberships on the same online contribution page.

This doesn't make sense, because none of the Membership options have an auto-renew option.

I am on civi 4.7.27 and Wordpress 4.9

***SCREEN SHOTS ADDED***
[image: contribution settings]

[image: Membership Settings]

Comment: can you post screenshots of your contribution and membership page settings?

Comment: Posted two screen shots.

Comment: Can you double check that you don't have a recurring payment option enabled for any of the memberships? Also, a little thought - what if you turned your memberships into a Membership Price Set and enabled that - would it produce the same error?